# Attendance API from zoho people in postman

Tags: json, api, postman, data-extraction, zoho

I am trying to get data of attendance API from zoho people in postman application .. so for this i already get access token and now i am trying to access all data ..

I tried this link and paste in get

https://www.zoho.com/people/help/api/attendance-api.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is the URL for the help page. (Please note that Zoho has announced they are doing away with authtokens and transitioning to [OAuth](https://www.zoho.com/people/api/oauth-steps.html)). Having said that, the URL I am currently using to access an employee's attendance data looks like this:

> `https://www.zoho.com/people/api/attendance/getAttendanceEntries?authtoken=[YOUR AUTH TOKEN]&empId=[EMPLOYEE ID]`